# How could I get a dict having max value for a key in a list containing multiple dict?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list

```
result = [{"name": "A", "score": 35, "other_details": ""},
          {"name": "A", "score": 60,"other_details": ""},
          {"name": "B", "score": 45, "other_details": ""}, 
          {"name": "B", "score": 34, "other_details": ""},
          {"name":"C", "score": 65, "other_details": ""}]
```

Now, I want to get the whole dictionary on the basis of maximum score for each name.

My expected output is:

```
[{"name": "A", "score": 60,"other_details": ""}]

[{"name": "B", "score": 45, "other_details": ""}]

[{"name":"C", "score": 65, "other_details": ""}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: I have shown my expected output @Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

result = [{"name": "A", "score": 35, "other_details": ""},
          {"name": "A", "score": 60,"other_details": ""},
          {"name": "B", "score": 45, "other_details": ""}, 
          {"name": "B", "score": 34, "other_details": ""},
          {"name":"C", "score": 65, "other_details": ""}]

data_result = [max(list(v), key=lambda x: x["score"]) for k, v in groupby(sorted(result, key=lambda x: x["name"]), lambda x: x["name"])]
print(data_result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'A', 'other_details': '', 'score': 60},
 {'name': 'B', 'other_details': '', 'score': 45},
 {'name': 'C', 'other_details': '', 'score': 65}]
```